# IE 7 anchor background

Tags: html, css, xhtml, internet-explorer-7

Why does IE 7 not handle, the css background property for anchors?

css:

```
.nav a
{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.nav a:hover
{
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#">anchor</a>
</div>
```

It has no background, but only in ie7. Why?

Comment: Can you use `background-color` just to make sure it isn't that?

Comment: also, can you post a URL or the full HTML for the page? IE7 has lots of hover bugs, but most of them only show up when the link elements are wrapped in "interesting" other elements, are dynamically manipulated wtih script, etc.  So seeing page context will help.

Answer (score 2):

What color is the surrounding background? If it's also white, then this won't work in any browser.

If page color is non-white, it's worth trying the solution recommended in this blog post: http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762: ading a DOCTYPE to your page to force IE7 into standards-compliant mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

If that doesn't work, other solutions I've seen include:

- put the `display:block` style on the link

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are using a strict doctype to get hover working in IE7:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```